# How to say "I don't need change" politely when paying a bill

Tags: traducción

In French, when we pay cash for a meal at the restaurant, we use the expression "c'est complet" (lit. está completo) to signify that the difference between the price of the meal and the amount left in cash is intended as a tip for the waiter/waitress. It's considered more graceful/polite than explicitly saying "I don't need change."

Is there any Spanish equivalent to this expression?

Comment: Louism, I found very helpful and precise the answer given on this post: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-is-the-most-universal-way-to-say-keep-the-change Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they ask you if you want your change back:

> Quédese con el cambio

"keep the change"

or, if you are handing the money, before they say anything:

> Así está bien

"this is okay"

its inferred that you give them more money, and they can keep it.

Those are the more common ways I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

"The change" in Spanish is `El cambio` o `la vuelta`. You could use

> Puede quedarse el cambio / Quédese con la vuelta

o

> No necesito el cambio

Comment: Where does the expression "Quédese con la vuelta" comes from? It sounds a little bit awkward! I'd never heard about that before and I've been in many countries from Mexico to South America. For latin americans the first is absolutely accurate and it's very polite: "Puede quedarse con el cambio". The expression "No necesito el cambio" sounds so arrogant. Excuse but it is. I would prefer the answer from luisluix (more friendly) as an alternative of "Puede quedarse con el cambio".

Comment: En Chile es masculino: _Quédese con el vuelto_. (Espero que no sea polémico).

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, "No necesito el cambio" is more a(nother explicit) permission to the other part to keep the change than a boastful statement about one's economic grandeur. My father had a grocery store and I managed the cashier for quite some time. Those (among with "Para tí, majo" from some old ladies referring to the change) where the expressions I heard the most.

Comment: @Rodrigo. No me había dado cuenta que era así. El artículo y la palabra vuelta en femenino, no me hizo ver que era «quédese con el vuelto». Sí, estoy de acuerdo que también se dice así.

Comment: @Diego. Ok I didn't notice that way. But maybe it's about the way you say it

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, realize that the title of the question is "I don't need change" and that is understood as "Keep the change". Same happens in Spanish.

Comment: "No necesito el cambio" is not arrogant. Is a way of giving money without saying "I'm giving this to you", like luisluix phrase "Así está bien". I guess it has some historic reasons for this. But both options are not arrogant at all and doesnt mean anything like "I got a lot of money so keep that small amount" like it may sound