# ¿Hácelo? como en "Hácelo $20"

Tags: traducción, verbos

Estaba buscando información sobre *cómo se dice *keep the change* en español* y encontré este thread aquí en stackexchange:

[What is the most universal way to say "keep the change"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-is-the-most-universal-way-to-say-keep-the-change)

Ahora estoy confundida.
User983248 en su respuesta puso *hácelo*  $20 -> make it $20.
Si usamos el imperativo, debería ser *hazlo*, ¿no?
Si tratamos a un camarero de usted, deberíamos decir *hágalo*, ¿no?
No entiendo que modo verbal es *hácelo*?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Posiblemente es *hacelo*, palabra llana sin tilde en la *a*. Esa es la forma para *vos* del imperativo de *hacer*, como indica la respuesta de mdewey.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the conjugation given in the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/hacer?m=form#conjugacionfIOsOqS) for hacer and look down at the foot of the page for the imperative you will see that the user (User983248) probably comes from a part of the world where voseo is common. If, like me, you learned Spanish elsewhere then this always comes as a shock.